# How to block inbound messages from Firebase in Windows Firewall

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firewall, windows-firewall

I'm trying to setup a Windows Firewall rule to block inbound messages from Firebase (FCM).

The firebase documentation says that inbound messages are received by UDP on ports 5228-5230. I've therefore setup a rule to block the connection on these ports.

However, I still receive the messages.

This is obviously great for the resilience of Firebase listeners but I'm wondering if anyone can give me a pointer to block these inbound messages.
[image: Firewall General]
[image: Firewall Protocols and Ports]

Several posts have indicated that I would need to block the https port 443 but the firebase documentation indicates that **inbound** messages use only ports 5228-5230 so I am expecting that this (severe) restriction should not be necessary to block inbound messages.

For what its worth, I'm trying to replicate an environment where firebase is blocked by a firewall or other infrastructure in order to ensure that my app behaves correctly. I am therefore attempting to block all **inbound** messages to the firebase listener. I want to understand, if in these conditions, firebase will error (so that I can alert the user) or just silently fail to receive the expected messages.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: what type of message are you trying to block?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the Firebase documentation on [FCM ports and your firewall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messaging-ports-and-your-firewall):

> Ports to open for incoming messages:
>
> - 5228
> - 5229
> - 5230
> - 443

My guess is that most messages come in on that last port 443, which is HTTPS. Since you're not blocking that in your Firewall rules, the messages on port 443 are allowed.